# Как разделить для переноса слово двенадцать?

Tags: перенос

Как разделить для переноса слово двенадцать?В школе ребенку снизили оценку из-за того,что слово " двенадцать " было перенесено,как " двена-дцать "?Исправили на " двенад-цать ".Как правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Во всяком случае, исправили неверно.Вот если бы это было деление на слоги, то две-над-цать, потому что Ц-глухой звук, а по закону восходящей звучности после звонкого Д не может идти глухой Ц.

Но для переноса такое деление возможно, даже предпочтительно, потому что двенадцать=две/на/дцать(дцать=десять). Ребёнок показал знание морфем. Нельзя было бы оторвать Д от приставки НАД-:над-писать, над-пилить, а здесь как раз она(или он) перенесла так, чтобы не оторвать букву от корня: двена-дцать-корректный перенос.

При переносе сложных слов нельзя оставлять в конце строки начальную часть второй основы, если эта часть не составляет слога.

Неправильно:
пятиг-раммовый  Правильно:
пяти-граммовый, пятиграм-мовый. У Вас похожая ситуация, хотя сейчас нет современного корня -дцать-, но он вычленяется в сложных числительных.

Посмотрите задание, разделить нужно было для переноса или просто на слоги.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ!Был словарный диктант в школе,проверялась орфография,просто слово на строке не поместилось и нужно было перенести.

Comment: Я советую подойти к учителю и попросить объяснить, почему снизили оценку, ведь ребёнок знает, что дцать=десять , и не стал отрывать букву от корня, а Вы якобы посмотрели в словаре строения слов, там вычленяется корень -дцать-.В школьномграмматико-орфографическом словаре тоже, можете ей принести из библиотеки и показать. Пусть исправляет